# how to set pre_get_posts for only one query?

Tags: wordpress, sorting

i want using sorting in archive.php

so write this code in function.php

```
function change_order_for_links( $query ) {
    if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'pin_archive' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DEC' );
    }
}
function change_order_for_links_rate( $query ) {
    if ( is_main_query() && ( is_archive() || is_search() )) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_wpcr_rating_stars_avg' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DEC' );
    }
}
function change_order_for_links_view( $query ) {
    if ( is_main_query() && ( is_archive() || is_search() )) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'views' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DEC' );
    }
}
function set_ordering() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['order'] ) ) {
        $order = $_GET['order'];
        if ( $order == 'view' ) {
            add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_order_for_links_view' );
        } elseif ( $order == 'rate' ) {
            add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_order_for_links_rate' );
        }
    } else {
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_order_for_links' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_ordering' );
```

but this set for all query in the archive page
is_main_query() value's for all queries is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem
I must used `$query->is_main_query()`